# Sass ampersand and parent styles

Tags: css, sass

My HTML:

```
<div id="form" class="special">
    <div class="header">My special form</div>
<div>
```

And the following sass code:

```
#form {
  .header {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    .special & {
      background: $special-color;
    }
  }
}
```

Which produces:

```
#form .header {
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.special #form .header {
  background: #7cc52c;
}
```

However this doesn't give me the result I want. Instead of the CSS above I want to have: `.special#form .header` (*the element `form` **with** class `special`, not the element `.special` which has `form`*)

Comment: I've had that problem before, and I think it just doesn't work with the ampersand. If you find a solution I am curious. Btw: it's usually advised not to nest too deep with sass selectors (http://thesassway.com/beginner/the-inception-rule), so maybe simplify it? Do you really need id and class to select the element?

Comment: You can't do exactly what you want, but you could easily re-arrange the sass slightly to get the correct output: https://gist.github.com/rockerest/20272f20c689dafcbc1d2318c9368178. By the way, here's [here's the documentation for `&` saying you can't put it at the end of a compound selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector): "& must appear at the beginning of a compound selector, but it can be followed by a suffix"

Comment: Not that it will make a difference, but you are not closing your last `<div>` in your markup. Good points above btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired css this way.

```
#form {
  .header {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    @at-root #{selector-replace(&, '#form', '.special#form')} {
      background: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

This scss compiles to the following css

```
#form .header {
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.special#form .header {
  background: blue;
}
```

Using the `selector-replace` function, you can easily change the part of the compound selector that needs changing. In this example, that would be replacing `#form` with `.special#form`. The `@at-root` directive ensures that the selector is placed at the top level and not nested within any selector.

When the parent selector is appended and nested as you did in your question, it *reverses* the selector. There are situations where this might be useful, one such situation is when working with **Modernizr** as illustrated in one of the slides on [here](https://speakerdeck.com/imathis/sass-compass-the-future-of-stylesheets-now)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is by using @at-root and interpolation

```
$special-color:#7cc52c;
#form {
    .header {
        padding: 20px 10px;

        // use @at-root to move .special out of #form .header
        @at-root { 

            // append #form .header using the & selector  
            // note! you need to use interpolation #{} to 
            // remove the white space between .special and #form
            .special#{&} {
                background: $special-color;
            }
        }
    }
}
```